# Whats a Python Script/Method to use to get the number of fields with data in an attribute table?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop

I am doing some data migration and need the number of records with actual data, sans null and blank fields, without switching back and forth with select by attribute.

Ideally I would like to run a script for a table or feature class that gives me the count of each field that has data.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something along these lines:

```
import arcpy
fc = "MY FEATURE CLASS NAME AND PATH"

# Get list of fields
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]

# Set up dictionary for the fields
countdict = {}
for field in fields:
    countdict[field] = 0

# Loop through Table and see which fields are NULL or Blank
cur = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cur:
    for field in fields:
        if not row.getValue(field) in [None, " ", ""]:
            countdict[field] = countdict[field] + 1

# Print out results - shows field name and number of non NULL/Blank fields
for f in countdict.keys()
   print "%s - %s" % (f, countdict[f])
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking @dklassen snippet and enhancing a little with multiple tables iteration in a .gdb if that is the case. Outputs table name , total records , field name and number of non NULL/BLANK fields.

```
    from arcpy import env
    import arcpy

    # Set the current workspace
    #
    env.workspace = "your path here"


    # Get the list of tables in the geodatabase 
    # print to interactive window.
    # get total count records + count of fields excluding nulls/blanks

    tableList = arcpy.ListTables()
    tableCount = 0
    for table in tableList:
        tableCount += 1
        count = arcpy.GetCount_management(table)
        print "******* Table - " + table + ". counts " + str(count) + " records. *******"
        # Get list of fields
        fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table)]
        # Set up dictionary for the fields
        countdict = {}
        for field in fields:
            countdict[field] = 0
        # Loop through Table and see which fields are NULL or Blank
        cur = arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
        for row in cur:
            for field in fields:
                if not row.getValue(field) in [None, " ", ""]:
                    countdict[field] = countdict[field] + 1

        # Print out results - shows field name and number of non NULL/Blank fields
        for f in countdict.keys():
           print "%s - %s" % (f, countdict[f])

    print "Total tables counted:  " + str(tableCount)
```